# Calculating the variance of the time until a Markov process jumps to a specific state from a starting state?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

> 5. A Markov process on $E = {1, 2}$ is constructed according to holding time parameters $λ_1 = 2$ and $λ_2 = 4$; the defining Markov
>      chain has transition probabilities $p_{11} = p_{12} = 0.5$ and $p_{21}
>    > = 1$.
>
> (a) Calculate the generator matrix for this process.
>
> (b) What is the variance of the time (starting from state 1) until the
>   process jumps to state 2? Justify your answer.

I've calculated my generator matrix: \begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & 1   \\
    4       & -4  \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
However I'm a little unsure for part (b). Here is my attempt:

I think the variance is given by $\frac{1}{λ_1^2} = \frac{1}{4}$.
This is because the memoryless property of the exponential holding times mean the remaining time in a state $i$ is distributed exponentially with parameter $λ_i$ and the variance of an exponential distribution with parameter $λ$ is $\frac{1}{λ^2}$.

Is this satisfactory/correct?

Answer (score 1):

The process stays in state $1$ an exponential amount of time with mean $1/\lambda_1$. The process then transitions to state $1$ with probability $1/2$ or to state $2$ with probability $1/2$.

Let $T$ be the time spent in state $1$ until the process reaches state $2$. As a hint, let us try to calculate $\mathbb{E}[T]$. By conditioning on the number of times $N$ the process visits state $1$ before visiting state $2$ we get

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[T] &= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[T \mid N = n] \mathbb{P}(N = n) \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[T \mid N = n] (1/2)^n \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[\text{Erlang-$n$ with parameter $\lambda_1$}] (1/2)^n \\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{n}{\lambda_1} (1/2)^n = \frac{2}{\lambda_1}.
\end{align}

The important steps are the conditioning on the number of times we visit state $1$ before visiting state $1$ and recognizing the third equality. Keeping this hint in mind, can you find $\mathbb{E}[T^2]$ so that you can get $\operatorname{Var}(T) = \mathbb{E}[T^2] - \mathbb{E}[T]^2$?

Comment: The Erlang distribution only crops up as a minor note in my course and I'm afraid I'm too far removed from actually calculating expectations rather than simply memorizing them to be able to figure out $E[T^2]$, but thank you for your help

Comment: A random variable with an Erlang-$n$ distribution with parameter $\lambda$ is the sum of $n$ independent identically distributed exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$. [See the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution). The variance of an Erlang-$n$ distribution is given on that page, so you will actually be able to determine $\mathbb{E}[T^2]$.